# Plotly R - error "`line.width` does not currently support multiple values."

Tags: plotly, r-plotly

When I run the following:

```
interactive_plot <- plot_ly(
  data = vep_wes_aff_rare_summary, 
  x = ~n, 
  y = ~mean_af,

  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  hoverinfo = "text",
  text = ~paste("Var: ", rsIDs, '<br><br>Cases:', n, '<br><br>Mean_AF:', mean_af),
  color = ~mean_af,
  size = ~n,
  marker = list(sizeref=0.1)
)%>%
layout(
  title = 'SFARI - SCN2A Variants<br>WES SNPs/ Indels filtered by VEP(High/ Mod)',
  xaxis = list(type = "log", title = "Cases", family='Courier New',size=22, color='#7f7f7f'),
  yaxis = list(title = "Average Allele Frequency", family='Courier New', size=22, color='#7f7f7f', tickformat = '.1%')
)
interactive_plot
```

I get this error:

```
Warning message:
`line.width` does not currently support multiple values.
```

I've tried commenting out a few of the `list(,,,)` lines. I have to do a demo and would prefer not errors/ warnings onstage.

Comment: Consider trimming the unnecessary elements (eg, `color` and the call to `layout()`) and using a dataset that other have access to, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269.

Comment: You may want to look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692760/spurious-warning-when-mapping-marker-size-in-plotly-r/52693058, this might be a duplicate